# 32 bit Ubuntu thinks it works on 64 bit

Tags: nvidia, 64-bit, steam, 32-bit

So I just installed Ubuntu recently (on an NVIDIA Tegra if that matters)
I was trying to update but system always ignored 32 bit (i386) packages, thinking it is actually 64, downloading only those. It wouldn’t matter, but I can’t install Steam, and many of things can’t be done. How do I switch it to right one?

I found out that Linux for Tegra is only 64, when my Tegra X1 is 32 bit. Is there any way of stopping the system ignoring i386 packages? Is there away to make system think it actually is 32?

Comment: We don't know your release details, or your software stack (ie. what kernel etc you are using as LTS releases offer two stacks). A quick search online also tells me it's not i386 or amd64 at all, but an ARM architecture, so cannot use i386 as it's the wrong architecture (and bit size doesn't matter).  Your cpu is armv7 or arm64 neither of which is i386 or amd64 as they are incompatible being a different architectures.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search online also tells me [Nvidia Tegra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegra) it's not i386 or amd64 at all, but an ARM architecture, so cannot use i386 or amd64 as it's the wrong architecture (and bit size doesn't matter).

Your cpu is armv7 (32-bit ARM) or arm64 (64-bit ARM) neither of which is *i386* or *amd64* as they are incompatible being a different architectures.

*i386* is the 32bit x86, which is not compatible with *armv7* (32bit ARM).
*amd64* is the 64bit x86_64, which likewise is not comptable with *arm64* (64bit ARM)

ARM use very different *opcodes*, so program code for one architecture can only be used as program data on the wrong architecture. To execute ARM code on AMD64 processors you need interpreters that execute it, and likewise ARM requires an interpreter so it could process AMD64 code (or i386 code too), the results of which are comparatively slow & need loads more memory that code executed without interpreter.  Even if you have loads of RAM and can run an interpreter, the results are usually not *fun* with games due to loss of speed.